# how to change the path in the build folder of index.html file using webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, webpack

When i run `npm run build` am getting build folder and index.html and other files as well.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/main.5ecd60fb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function (e) { function r(r) { for (var n, p, l = r[0], a = r[1], f = r[2], c = 0, s = []; c < l.length; c++)p = l[c], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p) && o[p] && s.push(o[p][0]), o[p] = 0; for (n in a) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, n) && (e[n] = a[n]); for (i && i(r); s.length;)s.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, f || []), t() } function t() { for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) { for (var t = u[r], n = !0, l = 1; l < t.length; l++) { var a = t[l]; 0 !== o[a] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = p(p.s = t[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function p(r) { if (n[r]) return n[r].exports; var t = n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, p), t.l = !0, t.exports } p.m = e, p.c = n, p.d = function (e, r, t) { p.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, p.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, p.t = function (e, r) { if (1 & r && (e = p(e)), 8 & r) return e; if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var t = Object.create(null); if (p.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) p.d(t, n, function (r) { return e[r] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, p.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return p.d(r, "a", r), r }, p.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, p.p = "/"; var l = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] || [], a = l.push.bind(l); l.push = r, l = l.slice(); for (var f = 0; f < l.length; f++)r(l[f]); var i = a; t() }([])</script>
    <script src="/static/js/2.4b18b928.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/main.eab12189.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

but am expecting the src path to be like this in index.html. for eg if the src path is              `<link href="/static/css/main.5ecd60fb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">` but am expecting to be like this `<link href="./static/css/main.5ecd60fb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="./static/css/main.5ecd60fb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function (e) { function r(r) { for (var n, p, l = r[0], a = r[1], f = r[2], c = 0, s = []; c < l.length; c++)p = l[c], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p) && o[p] && s.push(o[p][0]), o[p] = 0; for (n in a) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a, n) && (e[n] = a[n]); for (i && i(r); s.length;)s.shift()(); return u.push.apply(u, f || []), t() } function t() { for (var e, r = 0; r < u.length; r++) { for (var t = u[r], n = !0, l = 1; l < t.length; l++) { var a = t[l]; 0 !== o[a] && (n = !1) } n && (u.splice(r--, 1), e = p(p.s = t[0])) } return e } var n = {}, o = { 1: 0 }, u = []; function p(r) { if (n[r]) return n[r].exports; var t = n[r] = { i: r, l: !1, exports: {} }; return e[r].call(t.exports, t, t.exports, p), t.l = !0, t.exports } p.m = e, p.c = n, p.d = function (e, r, t) { p.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, { enumerable: !0, get: t }) }, p.r = function (e) { "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: "Module" }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", { value: !0 }) }, p.t = function (e, r) { if (1 & r && (e = p(e)), 8 & r) return e; if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e; var t = Object.create(null); if (p.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", { enumerable: !0, value: e }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e) for (var n in e) p.d(t, n, function (r) { return e[r] }.bind(null, n)); return t }, p.n = function (e) { var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () { return e.default } : function () { return e }; return p.d(r, "a", r), r }, p.o = function (e, r) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r) }, p.p = "/"; var l = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] = this["webpackJsonpmy-app"] || [], a = l.push.bind(l); l.push = r, l = l.slice(); for (var f = 0; f < l.length; f++)r(l[f]); var i = a; t() }([])</script>
    <script src="./static/js/2.4b18b928.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./static/js/main.eab12189.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

whenever i do `npm run  build` i have to open the index.html and change the path manually. Am just prepending the '.' before the path. But am expecting this to be done at the time of build itself using webpack.

webpack file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    option: {
                        minimize: true,
                        attributes: {
                        root: '234234',
                        }
                    }
                }],
            }
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: 'index_bundle.js'
          }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Comment: what does your webpack file look like?

Comment: i have added the webpack file

Comment: thanks. Is there a reason you don't want to use the style/css loader?

Comment: i have to use css loader but my problem is the src path in index.html

Comment: I'm sorry I think I misunderstood your question. Its not that the src path is constantly changing but more so that you don't want to have to use ./ in the src path?

Comment: am getting / followed by the path in the src after build but i need the src path to be like ./

Comment: i hope u understood the scenario now

Answer (score 4):

[`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath) should meet your demand:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    option: {
                        minimize: true,
                        attributes: {
                        root: '234234',
                        }
                    }
                }],
            }
        ],
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: 'index_bundle.js',
            publicPath: './'
          }
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used `"homepage": "./",` in package.json it worked for me as well

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your `.env` file:

```sh
PUBLIC_URL='./'
```