# add parameter to request URL

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I am serving a static file(.js) using script tag (due to webpack). So the request url is like `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` But I want to add parameter to this request URL like this:
`http://localhost:8080/bundle.js/abc`

And according to parameter I will modify bundle.js and serve it.

But How can I add the params.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766253/how-to-change-the-path-in-the-build-folder-of-index-html-file-using-webpack) could help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change the path in the build folder of index.html file using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64766253/how-to-change-the-path-in-the-build-folder-of-index-html-file-using-webpack)

Comment: @radar155 This will not add parameter to this

Comment: it will. I sent a general solution to modify the path generated by webpack. Also, I would suggest you adding query string params instead of an url param for this purpose. Check also [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2329)

Comment: @radar155 I can modify the path thorugh which I can add `abc` to url. But the params are not only `abc` It can be anything based on user.

Comment: So you need to add client side logic to request the bundle script with a dynamic param. Webpack, node.js and express are not involved in this process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your goal.

But if you use express to serve your bundle.js (as mentioned in the post tag), to use the parameters, you can do something like :

```js
app.get("/bundle.js/:foo?", (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.foo === "bar") {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/src/bundle2.js");
  } else {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/src/bundle.js");
  }
});
```

Here is a codesandbox with this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-74429869-7iz7l2?file=/app.js:242-435

Comment: How to add `:foo` this param in the URL. Currently the URL only contains `/bundle.js`

Comment: what do you mean? are you talking about the generated index.html from webpack, that is including a script tag pointing just to `bundle.js` ?

Comment: Are you really using express as mentioned by your post tag or are you only using webpack dev server?

Comment: @radar155 yes its pointing to bundle.js so the url will only `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` But how can I add params to it.